# CreateWindowEx fails with GetLastError returning 0; DefWindowProc is called in WindowProc

Tags: windows, winapi

I just had a problem, while creating a window with WinAPI, which took me an embarrassing long time to solve.

The call to `CreateWindowEx` failed, returning 0. `GetLastError`, called immediately afterwards, also returned 0.

When I set a breakpoint on `DefWindowProc`, my debugger confirmed that it was being called, as it should be.

I've included a minimal example below. Why is the call to `CreateWindowEx` failing?

### WndProc

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
        HWND hWnd,
        UINT msg,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        return 0;
    }

    // LRESULT WINAPI DefWindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, lParam, wParam);
}
```

### The call to CreateWindowEX

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, // dwExStyle
    CLASS_NAME,             // lpClassName
    WINDOW_NAME,            // lpWindowName
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // dwStyle
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,       // x, y
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,       // width, height
    NULL,                   // hWndParent
    NULL,                   // hMenu
    hInstance,              // hInstance
    NULL                    // lpParam
);
if (NULL == hWnd) {
    //GetLastError();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally switched the `wParam` and `lParam` values I was passing to `DefWindowProc`.

Giving the function arguments in the proper order solved my problem.

```
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```